# Solving from equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am currently having trouble getting the correct answer on a sample problem and I can not figure out why.

I have the following:   $\frac{3y}{8}$ and I am trying to get it in the form $\frac{2y}{x}$ to solve for $x$.

The answer comes out to be $15$ but I can not figure it how to get there. So the final answer should read $\frac{2y}{15}$

I started by doing $\frac{3y}{8} = \frac{2y}{x}$ and keep getting answers around $5$ for $x$.

Can anyone explain how I get to $15$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{3y}{8}=\dfrac{2y}{x}\\
\implies x=\dfrac{16}{3}$$
You are correct. $15$ is wrong.